# raid5 after changing disk, data disappeared in lost+found or?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, software-raid

I lost a drive so I stopped my array, changed the drive, reassembled the array.

So far so good except that when I tried to mount the array I had an error about md0 file system (sorry I rebooted so can't paste it from dmesg, something like ioctl failed..)

So I did a **`sudo fsck -f -y /dev/md0`** retrospectively I think a mistake, but that's done now...

Now I can mount without any issue my array using **`sudo mount /dev/md0 /media/raid5`**
The problem is that there is no data when I issue a **`ls -la /media/raid5`** except a bunch of things in lost+found...

I pasted below some stuff that may help ; have I lost my data or is it recoverable ?

The thing I find "strange" is the size of the array in the detail, dunno if it's related but Array Size : 7813527552 seems correct while Used Dev Size : 1953381888 seems too low, in fact the size of the data I'm missing is exactly the difference, 5To..

**`df - h`** tells me I effectively use those 5To, seems like they are 'hidden' in lost+found, aren't they ? if that's the case any means to get it back, even partially ?

```
➜  ~  sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Nov  6 15:41:25 2012
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 7813527552 (7451.56 GiB 8001.05 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953381888 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 5
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Dec 15 14:27:06 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 5
Working Devices : 5
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : bigbenn:0  (local to host bigbenn)
           UUID : e7c87d29:37d0d6b4:9a336d4f:0e239a13
         Events : 188191

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       6       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       7       8       81        1      active sync   /dev/sdf1
       5       8       97        2      active sync   /dev/sdg1
       4       8        1        3      active sync   /dev/sda1
       8       8       49        4      active sync   /dev/sdd1

➜  ~  df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1        37G  3.2G   32G  10% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.4G  9.4M  2.4G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb6       189G  1.3G  178G   1% /home
/dev/sde1       917G  743G  128G  86% /media/backup
/dev/md0        7.2T  5.0T  1.9T  73% /media/raid5
tmpfs           1.2G  4.0K  1.2G   1% /run/user/117
tmpfs           1.2G  4.0K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000

➜  ~  ls -la /media/raid5
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec 15 00:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Dec 14 21:49 ..
drwx------ 6 root root 4096 Dec 15 00:39 lost+found

➜  ~  ls -la /media/raid5/lost+found
ls: cannot open directory /media/raid5/lost+found: Permission denied
➜  ~  sudo !!
➜  ~  sudo ls -la /media/raid5/lost+found
total 475124
drwx------  6 root       root             4096 Dec 15 00:39 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root       root             4096 Dec 15 00:39 ..
p-------w-  1  489050452  252528908          0 Jun 27  1977 #261633
cr-x---rwx  1 1143560789  640026744    23, 112 Jan 12  1977 #261639
cr-s--x-w-  1  559564848  139876864     4,  26 Jan 20  1977 #261640
b------r-t  1 1853311824 1869352991   109,  10 Sep 28  1998 #261654
c--Sr-Srwt  1  541667594  825704759    68,  52 Oct 16  2006 #261659
p--s-w--wt  1  542639642 1412387656          0 Feb 25  2020 #261667
pr---w-r-x  1  268895754  203120431          0 Nov 16  2025 #261674
pr-srw--wT  1 1814436894 1412593526          0 Nov  9  1975 #261706
pr---wxr-T  1   22284047  236801860          0 Jun  8  2016 #261721
cr-x-w-r--  1  492048252 1951075159    83,  94 Oct 25  2015 #261733
pr-s-w--wt  1 1128532501 1097551966          0 Feb  1  2019 #261741
pr--------  1 1547961346  442260057          0 Jun 30  2003 #261781
pr-srwS-wT  1 1079076920    7603464          0 Dec 22  1977 #261782
c--Srw---T  1  572405313 1160339301    68,  10 Apr  8  1974 #261784
p--srwxrwx  1  858325523 1563754496          0 Jul 19  1984 #261813
pr----Srwx  1 1448935536  558899787          0 Apr  8  2014 #261823
cr-x-w-r--  1 1599754272  626415711     2,   3 Jul 21  2018 #261832
pr-S--s-wx  1   38601258 1645485660          0 Sep  2  1978 #261835
cr-x--S-wt  1 1294991628 1176834053    80,  93 Apr  7  2014 #261844
p--Sr-sr-t  1   33620230  352323141          0 Sep 13  1972 #261846
pr-s--x-wt  1 1113021275  857099109          0 Mar 13  2006 #261868
c---r-x---  1  443308357  421205766    90,  80 Oct 16  2015 #261870
pr---wsr--  1 1966300955   24269653          0 Mar 13  1979 #261883
cr-SrwSrw-  1 1532772663  994263811    81,  94 Apr 16  1974 #261893
pr-S--S--x  1 1448562180  558961927          0 Nov  5  1974 #261895
c--S-w-rwt  1 1446058509  575937801    86,   7 Aug 17  1979 #261900
cr-x-wxr-t  1  441538073 1095238738    73,  23 May 22  2007 #261936
cr-x--s--t  1 1461457223  287135574     3,  59 Mar  3  2005 #261938
c--x--Sr-T  1 1092879959 2065648452    28,  68 Apr  2  1982 #261954
p--S--SrwT  1  207227675 1499218280          0 May 19  1976 #261955
p-----x-wx  1  118380373 1912872706          0 Sep  4  1995 #261957
pr-x-wsrw-  1  626543116 1431831044          0 Oct 15  2013 #261959
pr-S--S--T  1 1363739136  944773205          0 Oct 16  2005 #261966
pr-------T  1 1912867116  118571589          0 Jan 29  1985 #261996
b--s--S-wx  1 1918324566   34037084    23,   6 Sep  6  1972 #261998
pr-S--xr-T  1    1251093  508183892          0 Feb  7  1987 #262003
pr------wx  1 1260539999 1348032039          0 Sep 18  1988 #262007
p----w---T  1    4265242 1498378579          0 Oct  5  2005 #262040
pr-s--S-wt  1  219960592  168580888          0 Nov 25  1991 #262048
p--s-w--wt  1 1398086148 1074290245          0 Jul  4  2009 #262062
cr--r-srwt  1  639778115 1980330242    77,  73 Aug 15  2019 #262065
br-s--S-wt  1 1226462797  101450497     2,  28 Nov 28  2110 #262068
pr-S--s---  1  353574159  453641563          0 Sep  5  1987 #262070
p----ws-wx  1 1577064198  189334030          0 Jul 25  2018 #262087
p--s--s--T  1  558370393 1685343820          0 Apr 19  1983 #262096
p--s--Srw-  1   17201021  385880331          0 Jun  9  1985 #262101
p--x--Srwx  1   41312810  101461250          0 Aug 22  2005 #262119
br-s--sr--  1 1129711117 1112808966    23,  22 Dec 15  2008 #262125
pr----Sr--  1  420895034  236208449          0 Sep  3  2020 #262128
s---rwxr--  1 1688325333 1881631676          0 Sep  2  1941 #3876
s--s-wsr-t  1  332108683  934059802          0 Jul  1  1995 #3916
-rw-r---wt  1 1460211467 2815708698      36864 Mar  2  1929 #3917
b-w-r-S---  1  865474894   47585693    62,  39 May 14  1990 #3919
-r-S-wsrw-  1 3778435245 3291066133      49152 Jul  4  1977 #3956
d--xr-x--t  2  669314516 2513519167       4096 Nov 20  1969 #3966
d--s--xr-T  2  954465812 2472467194       4096 Oct 14  1916 #3983
sr-S---rwT  1  938580216 2490859683          0 Apr 27  1942 #4003
--w-r-Srwt  1  337826943 1400506028      32768 Feb 21  1980 #4025
srwS-w--wx  1 3429655040 1853513202          0 Aug 30  2022 #4040
s-wS--s--x  1 3122972322 3846267154          0 Aug 18  1918 #4066
br-Sr-s--x  1  195341673 1718203134   145, 246 Apr 29  1929 #4076
cr-x--xr-T  1 3365232875 3635400453    88, 231 Oct 10  1957 #4085
srw---Sr-T  1 3121937149 3368475388          0 Jul 20  1920 #4091
s-ws--Srwt  1 2681996022 3739450654          0 Mar 22  1961 #4092
drwxr-xr-x 27 lotso      lotso            4096 Dec  7 08:38 #4098
-rw-------  1 root       root       4299210752 May 16  2014 #4103
-rw-------  1 root       root        134217728 Nov  6  2012 #4104
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso         4072611 Sep 21  2013 #4116
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso        11033891 Nov 19  2013 #4127
-rwxr-xr-x  1 lotso      lotso         6679717 Dec 26  2012 #4128
drwx------  2 root       root             4096 May 21  2013 #4130
-rwxr-xr-x  1 lotso      lotso         4373740 Mar 22  2013 #4131
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso        16269232 Jul 29  2013 #4132
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso        14832814 Jul 29  2013 #4133
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso         4979773 Jul 29  2013 #4134
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso        16523930 Jul 29  2013 #4135
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso        10224111 Jul 29  2013 #4136
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso        29414204 Jul 29  2013 #4137
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso         9604110 Jul 29  2013 #4138
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso         5406142 Jul 29  2013 #4139
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso         1325863 Jul 29  2013 #4140
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso         3037985 Jul 29  2013 #4141
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso         7495354 Jul 29  2013 #4142
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso          847820 Jul 29  2013 #4143
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso         3754492 Jul 29  2013 #4144
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso        41141215 Sep 21  2013 #4145
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso          613446 Sep 21  2013 #4146
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso        47836769 Sep 21  2013 #4147
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso        18449218 Sep 21  2013 #4148
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso         5419992 Sep 21  2013 #4149
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso         2584180 Sep 21  2013 #4150
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso          156546 Sep 21  2013 #4151
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso        20297183 Sep 21  2013 #4152
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso         4207536 Sep 21  2013 #4153
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso         1008568 Nov  8  2013 #4154
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso         1112122 Nov  8  2013 #4155
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso         4187507 Nov 19  2013 #4157
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso         1900671 Nov 19  2013 #4158
-rw-r--r--  1 lotso      lotso          792373 Nov 19  2013 #4159
```

Comment: Looks like it's restore from backup time.

Comment: Managed to get most of the files thanks to this post : http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2010/06/09/how-to-recover-files-from-lostfound-after-fsck-in-linux-how-i-did-it-in-ubuntu/comment-page-1/